# Looking for the multiplicity-free paper by N.Inglis

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, paper-request

I'm looking for the paper "Multiplicity-free permutation characters, distance-transitive graphs and classical groups, PhD Thesis, University of Cambridge, 1986" by Nicholas Francis John Inglis. The paper is cited several times ([Google Scholar says 10](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22Multiplicity-free+permutation+characters%2C+distance-transitive+graphs+and+classical+groups%2C+PhD+Thesis%2C+University+of+Cambridge%2C+1986%22)), e.g. John van Bon's "Finite primitive distance-transitive graphs".

The Google Scholar link directs to the EThOS service, but the EThOS service gives the message "Full text unavailable from EThOS".

Is it possible to find the paper?

Comment: I guess there is a copy at the University of Cambridge, but no idea if it is possible to get a copy without going to the library (the website there says "not borrowable"). In cases like this it is sometimes useful to look at other papers of the author, for example some results of the PhD thesis are in "Multiplicity-free permutation representations of finite linear groups" (joint w/ Liebeck and Saxl)  [link](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01164008). You might find whatever you are looking for there as well. Also, you could email and ask some people who are still active and have cited the thesis.

Comment: Update: the conclusion of the paper can be found in p.353 of Investigations in Algebraic Theory of Combinatorial Objects by I. A. Faradzev et al. and that's enough for my research, so there's no need to post an answer.